How to connect Athena ODBC using AWS learner lab
I downloaded the Athena ODBC to connect to amazon athena. When I go to configure a data source in ODBC data sources 64bit on my own computer, I can't seem to get the correct secret access key or access key. I've tried everything I found online on how I might find my keys but nothing works.
I can't create an IAM user as I am on a learner lab environment and that is not available to me. I also cannot retrieve the keys for the temporary user that is assigned to me. If this is option to connect to external data visualization tools is unavailable because of the nature of learner lab, I'm open to suggestions on alternative solutions.
